# Chrome grey text issue

Tags: google-chrome

I have an Issue with Chrome, where some pages show text in a grey way, making it hard to read or even impossible.

[image: 1]

I have tried all sort of things including uninstall and reinstall, clear cache, clear history, etc.

This only happens on my laptop. Chrome on my desktop is working fine.

Comment: Turn off hardware acceleration and see if that helps.